# Should I URL encode even if im not sending to a server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if URL encoding is recommended in all circumstances when using URL parameters.

Currently I am using window.history.pushState to update my querystring without reloading the page so that I can use the parameters in that URL to display certain things on my page that refresh. e.g a drop down that goes to the previously selected option when the page refreshes.

I have seen some people insisting that all my parameters should be encoded and decoded, but what if the values are only used for refrence, and not sent anywhere, do I really need to encode them, and if so, why?

Comment: Just because a parameter is not sent any where does not mean it's not important.  If the application uses it, then they are subject to change by the user, and could be used to potentially inject logic into your page that you otherwise did not intend to be executed.  It's a known attack vector for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Encode and decode is used to prevent unwanted injection into server or application. Even if you are not sending it to the server then also it may be risky. If you think that you are just using that as parameter to show or hide fields that will not be a part of any injection harm to the server or your information then you can go without encoding.

**But every professional developer would encode that even it is not sent to server.**

Comment: I´d say a professional knows when and when not to encode something. Encoding, when not really needed, just adds unnessesary code.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the application will be hosted locally, with limited access. The risk factor is extremely low from the start but i just want to be sure nothing obvious is left open to abuse. Thanks for the reply.